# jQuery Validation plugin - Have multiple "conflicting" rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My validate code is something like this:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        ...
        phone_number: {
            phoneUS: true,
            phonesUK: true,
            phoneNL: true
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

As you can see, I am using multiple conflicting rules (all phone numbers). My purpose is to cover validation across as many phone number syntaxes as possible.

With my code above, I'm using US, UK, and NL phone number validation as those are the ones that are, by default, packaged with `additional-methods.js`.

However, it doesn't work. It's not just one phone number doesn't work; all three types don't work. I tried inputting:

- 7815558923 (US)
- 781 555 8923 (US)
- 781-555-8923 (US)
- 01632 960881 (UK)
- 06-14147112 (NL)

All of those are fake, generated numbers I found online. Regardless, they all don't pass the validation, and I assume that's because I included all three of the validation rules.

So, question is, how do I have multiple validation rules to cover as much area as possible, while avoiding conflict that leaves the system broken?

Comment: You have to create your own custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method incorporating a new regex that covers your specifications.

Comment: @Sparky Could you give me some example code?

Comment: Using the search function, I see [over 300 questions with example code](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+addmethod).

Comment: @Sparky Alright thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should try to define phone number rules like this:

Here is simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dSz5j/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function (phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid us phone number");

    /*
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phonesUK", function (phone_number, element) {
        phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
        return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/);
    }, "Please specify a valid uk phone number");
    */

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I realize this, but this answer only covers US phone numbers. I want to cover US, UK, and NL (default provided by jquery validation plugin), but the rules conflict each other.